# Angular ngfor select all and deselect

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have items :

```
items: [
    {name: 'Name'},
    {name: 'Name'},
    {name: 'Name'}
]
```

I am showing them in html :

```
<ion-checkbox (click)="click(); selectAllItems()" class="checkboxas" [(ngModel)]="allTobuli"></ion-checkbox>
<!-- this isnt in ngFor and it Selects all items -->

<ion-card *ngFor="let item of jsonObj" class="relative" (click)="compareTobuli(item,i);checkboxTobuli(item)">
    <ion-checkbox (click)="compareTobuli(item,i)" [(ngModel)]="item.allTobuliItem" class="checkboxas absolut-check"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-card>
```

Each of them as you can see got checkbox - if you click on item it is added to another array and checkbox value becomes true. Another thing is that there is one checkbox out of ngFor which make another array same as items.

**The problem is that I don't know how to change ngFor all checkboxes values when clicking on checkBox which isnt in ngFor.**

I am using sets so it's my TS :

```
compareTobuli(item,i){
    if (this.selected.has(item)) {
        this.selected.delete(item);
        console.log('Trinam', this.selected)
    } else {
        this.selected.add(item);
        console.log('Pridedan', this.selected)
    }
}

click() {
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
    console.log(this.clicked);
    return this.clicked;
}

selectAllItems() {
    if(this.clicked == true) {
        this.selected = new Set(this.jsonObj);
        console.log(this.selected);
    }
    else {
        this.selected = new Set;
        console.log('deleted all', this.selected);
    }
}

checkboxTobuli(item){
    item.allTobuliItem = !item.allTobuliItem; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: 
Here is a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-iyvkcx) that also select and deselect all values on click.

You already use `(click)="click(); selectAllItems()"` on your `ion-checkbox` to call `click()` and `selectAllItems()`.

All you need to do is modifing the specific values (of the iterated items) inside these method.

```
selectAllItems() {
    for(let i=0; i<this.jsonObj.length; i++) {
        let item = this.jsonObj[i]; // this is your item from *ngFor="let item of jsonObj"
        item.allTobuliItem = true;  // select every single item
    }
}
```

Comment: can You please change your example to sets ?

Comment: I just added your lines to my selectedAllItems before Set, it is working perfectly.

Comment: Also have a look at the stackblitz i provided in order to also deselect items without additional function. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the value of `allTobuliItem` for each item in the `jsonObj`. Angular's data binding will take care of the rest. Example:

Template

```html
<ion-checkbox
  (click)="click(); selectAllItems()"
  class="checkboxas"
  [(ngModel)]="allTobuli"></ion-checkbox>
```

Component

```js
public selectAllItems() {
  this.jsonObj = this.jsonObj.map(item => {
    item.allTobuliItem = this.allTobuli;
    return item;
  });
}
```

Comment: The `item` in the code above and the `item` in the template in your question are different variables. In my example above item is a local variable that is assigned within the context of the map function.